# Pass data to modal using ngx-bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I am using angular 8 and ngx-boostrap to open modals and pass data from parent to modal. But not working as expected. What should I do to make it working?.. This my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-open-modal-duvzdx) demo and code

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">Open modal</button>
 
<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Just a modal with a {{initialState.data1}}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Component

```
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    const initialState = {
    data1 : 'foo'
}
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, {initialState});
  }
```

Comment: I think it doesnt work cause you dont have a separate component for modal, it's just a static view. In order to be able to pass properties it has to be it's own, separate component

Comment: oo.. I see..I will change it.. Thank you..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use it like this

**HTML**

```
<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal for data : {{ modalService.config.initialState.data1 }}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    This is a modal.
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**Component**

```
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    const user = {
        data1 : 'foo'
      };
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, {
      initialState : user
    });
  }
```

And this online [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-bootstap-p7ytx7)